# when apply session timeout after 20 minute i get error object null reference on session on startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side

I work on web application Blazor server side . I get error when apply session timeout reach to 20 minute then application will redirect to login page .

error happen on this block of code

```
  services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });
    services.AddScoped<ISession>(_ => _.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Session);
```

error

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost
EventId: 111
SpanId: b5f359c71bdf98dd
TraceId: 55c402b51115a74fe957d0762f8e004f
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 800002a3-0000-f500-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /_blazor
TransportConnectionId: GD0qeN4kpoisoFqdq7Lm_Q

Unhandled exception in circuit 'fsJjR_i80e4-G8BcnIas7mkmnqTlTY5vpTXVNEzo_Rg'.

Exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at UC.AppRepository.UI.Startup.<>c.<ConfigureServices>b__4_1(IServiceProvider _) in D:\test repository\BackupBlazor\UC.AppRepository.UI\Startup.cs:line 67
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateInitializer>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

details

I apply session timeout after 20 minutes

1 - create js on `wwwroot/js` file have function `checkSessionTimeout`

```
function checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl) {
    var sessionTimeout = 20 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutes in milliseconds
    var lastActivity = new Date(Date.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("LastActivity"))); // get the last activity time from the client-side session
  
    if (new Date() - lastActivity > sessionTimeout) {
        /*console.log("reach 2 minutes")*/
        


sessionStorage.clear(); // clear the session storage

} 
else 
{
    setTimeout(function () { checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl); }, 1000); // check again in 1 second
    }
    
    }
```

checkSessionTimeout(window.location.href);

2 - on page.razor

```
@inject ISession Session;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string nowString = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
JS.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "LastActivity", now);

}
```

3 - after component load call function `checkSessionTimeout`

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{

var lastActivity = Session.GetInt32("LastActivity");

if ( TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastActivity.Value) < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20))
{
    navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Login/Login");
    return;
}
}
```

4- on _host file on last line on body
I add the following :

```
<script src="~/assets/js/checksessiontimeout.js"></script>
```

5-on startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    });
services.AddScoped<ISession>(_ => _.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Session); line 67 that give me error 
}
```

So How to solve or prevent this error from happen ?

**Updated Post**

so can you tell me how to implement session timeout without using HTTP context .

can you show me please by code

if I avoid using http context so what solution for make that

Comment: so how to solve this issue remove this  services.AddSession(); or remove this  services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    });

Comment: i updated answer can you check please

Comment: if I avoid using http context so what solution for make that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just forget about using Session in Blazor server for now.

Blazor uses websockets, not http reqests/reponse model. Therefore:

1. you cannot use HttpContextAccessor in Blazor, since HttpContext is not always available. It usually works, when you just open the Blazor App, but later, it returns null.
2. When there is no HttpContext, there is no Session.
3. Session.Idletimeout does not work for Blazor, because it will timeout even when you are active (e.g. you click buttons or navigate inside the blazor app).

I can imagine some hacks that will allow you to use Session, but I would stick with what is supported.

Also, be aware that blazor session in not the same as http session (resp. ASP.NET Core session)

Comment: so can you tell me how to implement session timeout without using httpcontext

Comment: i updated answer can you check please

Comment: if I avoid using http context so what solution for make that

Comment: I suggest you to write completely new question where you describe exactly what you want to achieve (e.g. logout user after some time of inactivity)

Comment: can you please help me i make another thread as you advice me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108653/how-to-implement-session-timeout-without-using-http-context-on-component

Comment: But you asked basically the same question and the answer is the same - you can't use session in blazor

Comment: so tell me what i write i will do

Comment: i modified to session storage so are this correct

Comment: i change my question as you advice but i can't get answer