# How to implement session timeout with another way without using http context on component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on web application Blazor server side . I need another way to implement session  timeout instead of using http context .

I get more issues when implement session time out using http context

so I need another solution to solve that instead of using http context.

```
  services.AddScoped<ISession>(_ => _.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Session); line 67 that give me error
```

I apply session timeout after 20 minutes

1 - create js on wwwroot/js file have function checkSessionTimeout

```
function checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl) {
    var sessionTimeout = 20 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutes in milliseconds
    var lastActivity = new Date(Date.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("LastActivity"))); // get the last activity time from the client-side session
  
    if (new Date() - lastActivity > sessionTimeout) {
        /*console.log("reach 2 minutes")*/
        


sessionStorage.clear(); // clear the session storage

} 
else 
{
    setTimeout(function () { checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl); }, 1000); // check again in 1 second
    }
    
    }
checkSessionTimeout(window.location.href);
```

2 - on page.razor

```
@inject ISession Session;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string nowString = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
JS.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "LastActivity", now);

}
```

3 - after component load call function checkSessionTimeout

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{

var lastActivity = Session.GetInt32("LastActivity");

if ( TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastActivity.Value) < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20))
{
    navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Login/Login");
    return;
}
}
```

4- on _host file on last line on body I add the following :

```
<script src="~/assets/js/checksessiontimeout.js"></script>
```

5-on startup class (I get error on adding session timeout using http context )

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    });
services.AddScoped<ISession>(_ => _.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Session); line 67 that give me error 
}
```

How to implement session  timeout without using http context on component ?

**Updated Post**

when implement solution below I get error

```
InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(long asyncHandle, string identifier, string argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, long targetInstanceId)
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<TValue>(long targetInstanceId, string identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, object[] args)
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<TValue>(long targetInstanceId, string identifier, object[] args)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, string identifier, object[] args)
UC.AppRepository.UI.Pages.Database.Database.OnInitializedAsync() in Database.razor
+
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", "LastActivity",
```

Comment: i GET error when implement solution below can you please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a session timeout in a Blazor server-side application using a combination of JavaScript and Blazor's C# code.
Instead of using HttpContext, you can store the last activity timestamp in the local storage and use JavaScript to check for session timeout.

Remove the use of HttpContextAccessor and ISession in your project:

```
function checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl) {
var sessionTimeout = 20 * 60 * 1000; // 20 minutes in milliseconds
var lastActivity = new Date(Date.parse(localStorage.getItem("LastActivity"))); // get the last activity time from the client-side local storage

if (new Date() - lastActivity > sessionTimeout) {
    localStorage.clear(); // clear the local storage
    window.location.href = "/Login/Login"; // redirect to login page
} else {
    setTimeout(function () { checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl); }, 1000); // check again in 1 second
}
}

checkSessionTimeout(window.location.href);
```

In your Page.razor, remove the @inject ISession Session; line and modify the OnInitialized method:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string nowString = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", "LastActivity", 
nowString);
}
```

Remove the OnAfterRenderAsync method from your Page.razor, as the JavaScript code will now handle the session timeout check.

In your _Host.cshtml file, include the modified JavaScript file:

```
<script src="~/js/checkSessionTimeout.js"></script>
```

In your Startup.cs, remove the lines related to HttpContextAccessor and ISession. Your ConfigureServices method should look like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
}
```